# I want to send an email at 11 am everyday

Tags: python, django, email

I want to send an email at 11 am everyday by using Python.
But I do not know hot to send at 11 am everyday.Now,I can write a code to send an email.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def send?email(self):
        email = EmailMessage(subject, message, None, email_to)
        email.send(fail_silently=False)
```

I checked this document,but I could not find how to send an email at designated time.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html

Comment: You can use a scheduling tool, like `django-cron`: https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use cron (on Linux) or at (on Windows) at the required times.

this link is a good place to start 
https://medium.com/@harishoraon/writing-your-first-cron-job-in-django-ed62b805d822

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Advanced Python Scheduler` package. With that package it is easily possible to execute specific tasks at specific times. You can gather more information here https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather schedule this from a service rather than the other mentioned scheduling tools, I find **WayScript** to work particularly well for scheduling code runs.
[WayScript Platform](https://wayscript.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A crude, yet functional way of doing this would be to just run an infinite loop that checks the time and triggers the function if it's 11 am

```
import datetime
import time

while True:
    # Removing the date and microseconds from the full format
    t = str(datetime.datetime.now())[11:-7]

    if t == "11:00:00":
        send_email()

        # Wait for a second so it doesn't trigger the function more times
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I did a few test runs of this code and it worked each time, but yes it could very well happen. It would be better to also cut off the microseconds part of `t`, so only the seconds have to match and then have the loop sleep for a second so it doesn't double trigger